Proximal normals to a closed convex set.
I am interested in understanding the following infinite convex program:
$$ \underset{x \in R^{d}}{min} ||x-v||^2
$$
subject to the following infinite set of constraints:
$$ \langle \beta ,x \rangle \geq f(\beta)$$
for each $\beta \in \Delta_d$ (the probability simplex), $\beta_1=0$  and where $f$ is a non-negative real valued continuous function (but may not be differentiable).
Essentially this is trying to find the minimum distance of $v$ to the closed convex set
$$ \displaystyle C= \underset{\underset{\beta \in \Delta_d} {\beta_1=0}}{\cap}H_{\beta,f(\beta)}$$
where $H_{a,b}=\{x| \langle a,x \rangle \geq b\}$.
Q1) Let the unique minimizer of this problem be denoted as $\Pi_{C}(v)$. I am interested in the proximal normals $v-\Pi_{C}(v)$ defined by this optimization program. Intuitively, it feels  that if $x_0 \in Bd(C)$ then any proximal normal such that $\Pi_{C}(v)=x_0$ for some $v \notin C$ should be included in the conic hull of all $\beta$ that are active constraints at $x_0$ (i.e  $\beta$'s such that $ \langle \beta,x_0 \rangle=f(\beta)$).
How can we show that rigorously?
Q2) Under what condition on $f(\beta)$ can we show that the proximal normal for any point on $Bd(C)$ is just non-negative multiples of a single $\beta$? I guess from Q1 we can derive one sufficient condition that at each point in the boundary only one constraint is active. But $f$ turns out to be a complicated function and hence this might be hard to show. I am interested in other sufficient criteria that one can apply to $f$.
